# Ubuntu 16.04 - Wifi drops every few minutes

Tags: wireless, internet

My wifi drops every few minutes - I have to disconnect and reconnect it again (and occasionally turn off/on router). It works fine on windows and mobiles.

Power management is turned off, IPv6 method set as ignored didn't help.
When I go to Connection information and have a look at the speed, in case it works it shows 72 Mb/s, and when connection drops it blinks among 72 Mb/s, 1 Mb/s and unknown.

I am pretty new to ubuntu and programming, but here is some output:

Any help will be very appreciated.

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 10
       serial: 1c:1b:b5:99:df:54
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-112-generic firmware=34.0.0 ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:ed41c000-ed41ffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3c:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:ed204000-ed204fff memory:ed200000-ed203fff
```

```
ls -al /usr/src
```

```
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 Aug  5 15:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 Aug 12  2019 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov  1  2018 bbswitch-0.8
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Nov  1  2018 linux-headers-4.13.0-1021-oem
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 Jul  9 10:58 linux-headers-4.15.0-107
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Jul  9 10:58 linux-headers-4.15.0-107-generic
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 Jul 30 11:33 linux-headers-4.15.0-112
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Jul 30 11:33 linux-headers-4.15.0-112-generic
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Nov  1  2018 linux-oem-headers-4.13.0-1021
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Nov  1  2018 linux-oem-headers-4.13.0-1028
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jun 19  2019 nvidia-304-304.137
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov  1  2018 r8168-8.044.02
```

```
lspci | grep -i eth
```

```
3c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

```
ifconfig -a
```

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:35902 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35902 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2649364 (2.6 MB)  TX bytes:2649364 (2.6 MB)

wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:1b:b5:99:df:54  
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6184:774:6a7e:156c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:888497 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:268105 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1108557970 (1.1 GB)  TX bytes:56169269 (56.1 MB)
```

```
sudo lshw -C network | grep -i driver
```

```
 configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-112-generic firmware=34.0.0 ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

```
lspci
```

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a368 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a369 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a353 (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 21 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 9 (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a335 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30d (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
3b:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 0113 (rev 01)
3c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

Comment: Look at the logs! `sudo journalctl  -u NetworkManager`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - I changed router from O2 Box to TK-Link and it works now. What also partially worked, was to set wifi standard directly to 802.11 b, but the rate was very slow and I wasn't satisfied with this solution.

What didn't work for me, but could be possible solution for the others:

- Power management turned off
- IPv6 method set to ignored
- DNS Servers IPv4 set to 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
- iwlist channel    in terminal - and change router channel for the best wifi
- try ubuntu live 18.04  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started
- https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/intel-corporation-wireless-ac-9560-jefferson-peak-unstable/2829      edit conf file
- change wifi card?
- turn off bluetooth when wifi is used